# How to find out the overlapping area of circles?

Tags: geometry

[image]

this  problem can be solved by adding the lines and making a 30-60-90 degree.

But it seems a bit lengthy. Is there any short trick to solve this type math?.

Comment: The *structure* of the expression for the area indicates that the answer to your question is "probably not."